# Python PIL Imaging Library FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a tkinter (GUI) project that recieves the user's average and returns it to them. I wish to display images in my parent window using the PIL library. Yesterday this library was working fine and locating my image in the directory, but today it seems to not be able to find the directory, can someone please help me out and guide me. I don't know why the PIL library is acting up today, usually it's working fine. (I've tried reinstalling the files but not help!).

#### Here is my code

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tkinter.Tk();

def showImg():
    load = Image.open('Desktop\example.jpg')
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

    img = tkinter.Label(root, image = render)
    img.image = render
    img.pack()

button = tkinter.Button(root, text='Click me to see an image.', command=showImg).pack();

root.title('Imaging test');
root.geometry('450x450');
root.mainloop();
```

#### Here is my error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python [Learn]\imaging_example.py", line 7, in showImg
    load = Image.open('Desktop\example.jpg')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2219, in open
    fp = builtins.open(fp, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Desktop\\example.jpg
```

The text **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Desktop\example.jpg'** makes no sense to me. Just yesterday when I was using the PIL library, I was able to display images fine without receiving this error message, but today all I'm getting is this error message. I have even tried specifying the file path up to the C:\ but it won't accept it. Please someone help me out I need to get images in my tkinter (GUI) parent window but this library won't allow it. (P.S I have tried reinstalling PIL and it hasn't changed a bit, if you know any [easy to use] imaging libraries, please inform me of them).

*You should know:*

- I am running on Python 3.4.2
- Windows 8.1 machine
- I am not an Python expert, so please don't show me some complex code.

***Below is an image of my most recent error that i'm receiving. I've supplied a specific location to the image, and yet im getting this annoying error. ALSO SOMEONE EXPLAIN WHY THE DOUBLE  [ // ] SLASHES ARE THERE EVEN THOUGH I ENTERED ONLY 1. DOES THAT EFFECT MY FILES LOCATION? I'VE HIGHLIGHTED THEM IN YELLOW, SORRY FOR THE CAPS, I'M JUST TRYNA GET YOUR ATTENTION AND ALSO I'M NEW TO STACK OVERFLOW SO WOOPS :P*** 
[image: My error]

**Does it have something to do with this line:**
[image: Closer look.]

Comment: Where is your script and image located? What is your user name?

Comment: Try: `r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\example.jpg'`

Comment: Yeah that location above is the correct directory of where the file is located, but still i'm receiving the error, is there anything i can do, or is there a better way of writing the code (alternative)??

Comment: @PamalManagat What's your problem?

Comment: Where are your image and script? Give me absolute paths.

Comment: ***Script is located here*** : C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python [Learn]\imaging_example.py

Comment: ***Image is located here***: C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\example.jpg

Comment: I've supplied a new screenshot above please have a look at it my friend it may help you solve my problem

Comment: This literally works fine for me. Are you sure they're in the right places?

Comment: Alright did you happen to save the code? I could try to copy and paste it into my compiler and run it, if not then i'll write one up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your traceback your script seems to be located in - `C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python [Learn]\imaging_example.py`

But you are trying to access something inside (Desktop folder) using relative path - `Desktop\example.jpg` .

This would not work, unless your script is inside - `C:\Users\Pamal` .

Better would be to give absolute path, such as - `C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\example.jpg` .

Code -

```
load = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\example.jpg')
```

Comment: **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Pamal\\Desktop\\example.jpg'** *(I'm getting this error now)* Also  does the image have to be in the same directory/folder that my script is in? Finally, what does the r in Image.open(*r*'directory') mean/do? I tried being specific like you said but im still recieving an error, also i'm getting double slashes in the error even though i put in one FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Pamal\\Desktop\\example.jpg'

Comment: `r` before a string makes it a raw string, which means that the `\\` are not escape characters in it.

Comment: Okay thanks for explaining that to me, but dude it's still not working like i want it and i'm still getting the error is there anything else i can do? Also does the image have to be in the same location with the script or what?

Comment: I've supplied a new screenshot of an updated error message, after i made my directory path more specific.

Answer (score 2):

***Updated code:***
*I seemed to have gotten this error resolved but i don't understand how. I used a different image, in my pictures folder rather than the desktop and it seemed to work. Although i don't understand why?? Does anyone notice a difference in my 1st code and this one below?*

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you. I ran a program some months ago that works very well, but today it had the same error. What I did, which works for me, is change the directory to your home directory. For example, before, I loaded an image from a folder on my Desktop (i.e. `~/Desktop/images/example.png`), but I changed the directory to my Home environment (i.e. `~/home/pouyan/images/example.png`), and it worked without error.